# Dynamic regex based on runtime

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex which takes in a fixed list of disallowed characters already known + a dynamic disallowed list from runtime configuration.

Here is the code example. `disallowedChars` is the known list and `additioanlDisallowedChars`  comes from runtime configuration, which can be changed after the config is pushed.

```
 public static final String disallowedChars = "[^ \u2028 \u2029 \u0000-\u001f]+";
    public final String additioanlDisallowedChars = "";//TODO: HOW TO?
    public static final Pattern NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(disallowedChars);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String vowels = "అఆఇఈఉఊఋఌఎఏఐఒఓఔౠౡ";
        System.out.println(NAME_PATTERN.matcher(vowels).matches());
        System.out.println(NAME_PATTERN.matcher("a\u2029\u0000").matches());

    }
```

I know I can create a new pattern each time but it's expensive to my knowledge so wonder if there is a better way to check the additional disallowed list. Better to use regex since it would be clean but othe efficient ways are also welcomed

Comment: It looks like you want to check if a string contains some characters. I suggest to use `String::contains`.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post a sample value for `additioanlDisallowedChars`.

Comment: As you're dealing with non standard ASCII characters I'd recommend to use probably codepoints themselfs instead of relying on RegEx to simply check whether a character is admissible or not and maintain an array/list of int values of unwanted codepoints to check against. Codepoints have the benefit that you have one single value expressing the character regardless of its actual encoding while for simple `char` based characters you might end up with an additional surrogate character that might not be covered by the RegEx properly. Note that strings in Java are internally UTF-16 based

Answer (score 1):

If you change the format of `disallowedChars` from a regex pattern string to just a string of characters, you can concatenate `disallowedChars` and `additionalDisallowedChars`, bookend them with "[^" and "]+" like your original regex string, and then compile and use it.

```
public static final String disallowedChars = "\u2028\u2029\u0000-\u001f";
public static final String additionalDisallowedChars = GetAdditionalDisallowedChars();
public static final String regex = "[^" + disallowedChars + additionalDisallowedChars + "]+";
public static final Pattern NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String vowels = "అఆఇఈఉఊఋఌఎఏఐఒఓఔౠౡ";
    System.out.println(NAME_PATTERN.matcher(vowels).matches());
    System.out.println(NAME_PATTERN.matcher("a\u2029\u0000").matches());
}

public static String GetAdditionalDisallowedChars() {
    return "..."; // read from config
}
```

A few additional feedback items...

1. Your `disallowedChars` string contains multiple spaces. I'm not sure if you want to exclude a space or not but you don't need spaces between the characters. In my code I removed ALL of the spaces. Add one back in if you need it.
2. I corrected the misspelling in the `additionalDisallowedChars` variable name.

Comment: To deal with special chars in character classes, eg `-`, I would escape every one: `public static final String regex = "[^" + String.join("|", (disallowedChars + additionalDisallowedChars).split("")) + "]+";` (not tested!)